# Has anyone's figured out how to work around AG-Grid-Enterprise's aversion to React 16?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I have a demo app working for the high-ups in my company, and we're looking to add some of the Enterprise tools from AG-Grid. It's working beautifully with the community version, but even just adding the `import 'ag-grid-enterprise'` line (even if it's to one of their own example React one-pagers) causes it die an inglorious death with:

`TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`

Is this likely to be fixed?

> Side question: Is there some possible, straightforward, way to wrap it in some sort of iFrame, outside of React to get it to work?

( I suspect the powers-that-be will be reluctant to drop the $750 for me to buy support, when the answer will turn out to be "sorry, it's really just for Angular". :-( )

---

### Update:

Despite not yet paying for support, AG-Grid have kindly responded to an email query in short order. If it is something stupid I'm doing, I'll be sure to post it here.

---

### Update II:

So, `yarn upgrade` was no help ;-) but a complete `node-modules` rebuild did the trick. Afterwards, I realised that a `yarn upgrade-interactive` probably would have been as useful.

Comment: I use together: React, ag-grid, ag-grid Enterprise. It works fine. It also works in the demos on their site: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#auto-column-group (select React). Your question does not have enough detail to be answerable, you are probably doing something slightly wrong.

Comment: Agreed. Although, a quick Google does seem to suggest that I'm not the only one who's having the same issue.

Comment: My quick Google suggests that you should check to make sure that the versions of your AgGrid Community library, AgGrid React library, and AgGrid Enterprise library are aligned. Apparently, mismatched library versions can cause this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure that the versions of your AgGrid Community library, AgGrid React library, and AgGrid Enterprise library are aligned. Apparently, mismatched library versions can cause this error.

Also, try removing your node_modules and doing an `npm install`